# Download excel file with jqgrid complete data using jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I basically need complete data from JQGrid and populate to excel file.

```
 <input type="button" id="download" value="DOWNLOAD" />
```

controller , how to write `GetData();` method which has JQGRID data
NOTE: Now excel will download but its empty because of no `GetData();`
please help me out with `GetData();`

```
 public ActionResult ExportToExcel()

        {
            var pcmData = object_ProductCategaryMapping.ProductCategaryMappingGet();
            var Jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pcmData);

            var grdReport = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
            grdReport.DataSource = GetData(Jsondata);
            grdReport.DataBind();

            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            grdReport.RenderControl(htw);
            byte[] bindata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sw.ToString());

            return File(bindata, "application/ms-excel", "ss.xls");

        }

        public string GetData(string data) {

               // code here
            return data;
        }
    }
```

JQuery

```
$('#download').click(function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/PCM/ExportToExcel',
            success: function (response) {
                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/ms-excel' })
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a")
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = "ss.xls"
                document.body.appendChild(a)
                a.click()
            }
        })
        //exportGrid();

    })
```

or
Please say some other way to do it .
here in this site I found many method but tried and didnt find proper solution

Note: button is normal html button .(not JQGrid pagination button)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pcmdata` contain array of data

```
 public DataTable GetData() {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            var pcmData = object_ProductCategaryMapping.ProductCategaryMappingGet();
            dt.Columns.Add("Product Priority");
            dt.Columns.Add("Product Code");
            dt.Columns.Add("Product Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Category");
            dt.Columns.Add("SubCategory");
            dt.Columns.Add("Priority 1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Priority1 per");
            dt.Columns.Add("Priority 2");
            dt.Columns.Add("Priority2 per");
            dt.Columns.Add("Priority 3");
            dt.Columns.Add("Priority3 per");

            foreach (var obj in pcmData ) {
                dt.Rows.Add(obj.ProdPriority, obj.ProductCode, obj.ProductName, obj.Category, obj.SubCategory
               , obj.Priority_1, obj.Priority1per, obj.Priority_2, obj.Priority2per, obj.Priority_3, obj.Priority3per);
                
            }
```